# How to get Facebook access token from native Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to launch Native Facebook Application from my application by using following code. but after successful login how do i redirect to my app and also how to get access token?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",  "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you are follow the wrong way. You can read http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/ link or search 'facebook integration in android' on google.

Comment: You will not be able to retrieve the token from Facebook app.  If you could, that would present a serious security issue.  If you need to integrate your app with Facebook, check the link in @VivekKumarSrivastava 's comment.

Comment: i know how to integrate facebook in my app using facebook android sdk . but i want directly launch facebook native app for login and get access token and facebookid if user already login. i have seen some apps directly launching default facebook app instead of login of facebook android sdk.